# Is there a way to assign the object a pointer variable inside a class of the same name (c++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class. Inside this class is a *variable. This pointer variable points to other objects of the same class. However, when I try to assign public variables inside the object the variable is pointing to, I get an error message.

An example:

```
class Object(){
public:
  int varOne;
  *Object objectToInteract;

  void methodDoThing(){
    *objectToInteract.varOne = 1277;
  }
}
Object objectArray[10] //Contains a variety of Objects
```

Why does this not work? Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `*Object` is wrong - the `*` is always after the type name: `Object*`

Comment: `class Object()` is not correct, remove the round brackets

Comment: *"It's late. I'm tired."* -- sleep has been known to bring clarity to problems that had been driving one nuts...

Comment: `Object* objectToInteract = nullptr;` and `void methodDoThing(){ if (objectToInteract) objectToInteract->varOne = 1277; }`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like:

```
objectToInteract = &objectArray[3];

objectToInteract->varOne = 1277;
```